# Изменить иконку приложения nw.js в taskbar Windows 10

Tags: javascript, icon, nw.js, nwjs

я хочу изменить иконку моего nw.js приложения на свою. Вот js, который инициализирует окно.

```
(() => {
    const launchParams = {
        entryFileName: "resources/index.html",
        params: {
            frame: true,
            width: 1920,
            height: 1080,
            icon: "resources/images/logo.png",
        },
    };

    nw.Window.open(launchParams.entryFileName, launchParams.params, win => {});
})();
```

Проблема в том, что меняется только иконка на taskbar не изменяется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема явно не в пути к файлу, т.к. на предпросмотре иконка отображается. Как я могу это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то еще ищет ответ - вот. Иконку надо обязательно указывать в файле package.json, в документации это кстати не указано. Пример:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "resources/init.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",

  "window": {
    "icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```